# How to pass data to a wtforms QuerySelectField in flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm working on a app with RBAC and I'm trying to populate a QuerySelectField with data from my Role database model but it doesn't work because I'm constantly getting one of those two errors:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: <unprintable OperationalError object>
```

or

```
TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable
```

**models.py**

```
class Role(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement='auto')
  name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
  user = db.relationship('User', backref='role', lazy='dynamic')
  not_view = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
  not_edit = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
  not_add = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
  not_delete = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, EqualTo, Length
from app.models import Role
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField


def role_choice():
  return Role.query

class AddUserForm(FlaskForm):
  username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
  email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
  password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
  confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
  role_id = QuerySelectField(query_factory=role_choice)
```

I tried a few different ways of passing in data but none of them worked. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother to answer, I already solved the problem with a SelectField with a dynamic choice.

```
class UserDetails(Form):
   group_id = SelectField(u'Group', coerce=int)

def edit_user(request, id):
  user = User.query.get(id)
  form = UserDetails(request.POST, obj=user)
  form.group_id.choices = [(g.id, g.name) for g in Group.query.order_by('name')]
```